# Show that, for any sets $A$, $B$ and $C$ , $|A \times (B \oplus C)| = |(A \times B) \oplus (A \times C)|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to solve this question by defining a bijection between both sides of the equation, but I do not know how to define that bijection.

Let $A \oplus B = \{(0,a): a \in A \} \cup \{(1,b): b \in B\}$; this is the disjoint union of $A$ and $B$

**Proposition 1.** Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are two sets such that $|A| = m$ and $|B| = n$ for some $m, n \in \omega$. Then

1. $|A \oplus B| = m+n$;
2. $|A \times B| = m \cdot n$;
3. $|2^A| = 2^m$.

**Proposition 2.** For any sets $A$, $B$, and $C$,

1. $|A \oplus B| = |B \oplus A|$ and $|A \times B| = |B \times A|$;
2. $|A \oplus (B \oplus C)| = |(A \oplus B) \oplus C|$ and
   $|A \times (B \times C)| = |(A \times B) \times C|$;
3. $|A \times (B \oplus C)| = |(A \times B) \oplus (A \times C)|$.

So, for the multiplicative parts of $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have natural isomorphisms mapping $(a,b)$ to $(b,a)$ and mapping $((a,(b,c))$ to $((a,b),c))$. But for $(3)$ how to define that bijection?

My initial thought is like $F(a,(b,c))=((a,b),(a,c))$

Comment: For sets $X$ and $Y$, how do you define $X\oplus Y$?

Comment: @azif00  it's addition

Comment: I don't know what is that. Can you define it explicitly?

Comment: If $(a,(b,c))$ is an element of $A \times (B \oplus C)$, then $b$ is 0 or 1 and $c$ is either an element of $B$ or $C$ depending on the value of $b$. It may help to use other variables to represent these to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take an element $u=(a,(i,x)) \in A\times (B\oplus C)$, where $a\in A$, $i$ is $0$ or $1$ and $x$ is in $B$ or $C$, according to $i$ being $0$ or $1$. If $i=0$, then $(a,x)\in A\times B$, so you send $u$ to $(0,(a,x))$. If $i=1$, then $(a,x)\in A \times C$, so you send $u$ to $(1,(a,x))$.

That is $$(a,(i,x))\mapsto (i,(a,x))$$

Comment: Thank you! I think it makes sense.

Comment: @MathDD You're welcome. By the way, you wrote that  $(a,(b,c)) \mapsto ((a,b),c)$ works for $(2)$. But that's only for  $|A \times (B \times C)| = |(A \times B) \times C|$.  Are you aware that  $|A \oplus (B \oplus C)| = |(A \oplus B) \oplus C|$ needs a different bijection? Actually, that's the more difficult to define.

Comment: Yes, I know that (,(,))↦((,),) works for multiplicative parts. For the disjoint union, it needs a different bijection. so far I do not need to figure out that.